# How to write multiple queries with While loop in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have two correlated queries with while loop. I want to make it in a single query. below are my codes

```
<?php 
$selfaqCD=mysql_query("SELECT faq_cat_id FROM faq_cat WHERE faq_cat_status=1");
while($resfaqCD=mysql_fetch_array($selfaqCD)){?>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
<?php $selfaq=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE faq_status=1 AND fk_faq_cat_id='".$resfaqCD['faq_cat_id']."'");
while($resfaq=mysql_fetch_array($selfaq)){?>
<h4>Q: <?php echo $resfaq['faq_ques']; ?></h4>
<?php echo $resfaq['faq_ans']; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This isn't correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM faq a
     INNER JOIN faq_cat b ON a.fk_faq_cat_id = b.faq_cat_id
WHERE a.faq_status=1 AND b.faq_cat_status=1
```

Here's a guide about [SQL Join](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).